# uniform initialization on struct with in-struct initialised members

Tags: c++, c++11

Uniformed initialization of a struct instance which contains in-struct initialised members follows me to the following error on Apple LLVM version 7.3.0:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Foo'
```

Here is code sample:

```
struct Foo
{
    int foo1 = 0;
    int foo2;
};


int main()
{
    Foo foo{0, 1};
}
```

It seems that in-struct initialisation suppresses generation of initializer list struct constructor. Why?

Comment: FYI: There's no such thing as a "initializer list struct constructor". Applying `{}` to an aggregate does not use an initializer list; it simply performs [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), just like in C.

Answer (score 5):

Because you're compiling under C++11, which defines [default member initializers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) in terms of constructors. That is, they implicitly create a constructor. And therefore, the type is no longer an aggregate.

C++14 rescinded this, permitting aggregates to have default member initializers. The aggregate will override the default member initializer, if it provides an alternative.